# How to install winpdb (the python gui debugger) in 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, python

Has winpdb been removed from the repository in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Downvoters: please add a comment why. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

winpdb-reborn is a port of the discontinued Winpdb to wxPython 4 / Python 3. To install winpdb-reborn in Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip wxpython-tools
python3 -m pip3 install winpdb-reborn
```

Comment: No module pip3, but pip works.  Read the output for missing files. Use apt-file search gtk+-3  etc. to find the packages for the missing files, install them, try again until the build for wheel for wxpython succeeds.

Comment: @karel Thank you for you answer. I was asking specifically the Ubuntu repositry (Pip uses another process and online resource). Can you confrim that no other alternative is available in the repository?

Comment: I tried downloading a winpdb .deb file for Ubuntu 18.04, but I was unable to install it successfully in Ubuntu 22.04. Trying to install it in Ubuntu 22.04 generated a `held broken packages` error message because it couldn't find python2.7 which was installed and otherwise working correctly in my Ubuntu 22.04.